# selecting last square bracket input element in collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-input

This here JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3pLqa5n0/

The result contains an input element and a textarea element.

Each time you click on the first input element, it appends another input element and textarea element.

However, I want this to only happen when one clicks on the last input element (not the first).

In the code, I have done:

```
$('#deleteandadd input[name="inputName[]"]:last')
```

But the ':last' is obviously not working. How may I make this work?

Aside: when we use square brackets in element names, to send data to PHP, are these technically arrays?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `event delegation` at this context, since the last input element may differ every time when you append a new set of elements.

```
$("#deleteandadd").on("click",'input[name="inputName[]"]:last',function() {
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3pLqa5n0/1/)

Comment: Simply fantastic. I'll mark it as correct in 9 minutes. Can you please recommend me a resource for understanding "this" concept in JavaScript? I've googled around, but never quite understood it.

Comment: @user1883050 Read this link, its a nice resource.. http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: That is indeed nice. Thanks.